# ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, jenkins, junit, ant

```
<project basedir="." default="build" name="Calculator">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.8"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.8"/>
    <path id="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.junit_4.12.0.v201504281640/junit.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="Calculator.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <path refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="Calculator.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="AllTests">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="CalculatorProject.AllTests" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <jvmarg line="-ea"/>
            <classpath refid="Calculator.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="AdditionTest">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="CalculatorProject.AdditionTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <jvmarg line="-ea"/>
            <classpath refid="Calculator.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="Divide">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="CalculatorProject.Divide" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <jvmarg line="-ea"/>
            <classpath refid="Calculator.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="Multiply">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="CalculatorProject.Multiply" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <jvmarg line="-ea"/>
            <classpath refid="Calculator.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="SubtractTest">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="CalculatorProject.SubtractTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <jvmarg line="-ea"/>
            <classpath refid="Calculator.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="AllTestss">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="CalculatorProject.AllTestss" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <jvmarg line="-ea"/>
            <classpath refid="Calculator.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="junitreport">
        <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>
</project>
```

Having the error while running my project and its Junit test in Jenkins.
I also get an error 
"ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: None of the test reports contained any result".
And also having a dependency issue with the test.
Tried a few solutions but did not work
Any solutions?

Comment: What dependency issue? What are these few solutions you tried?

Comment: I read somehwhere that there might be a dependency issue, I dont know what exactly it means. But the solutions i tried were rebuilding the build.xml,changing the order of the tests in the xml,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to clean your target folder before you start , it will be easier for you to understand. looks like you have only old tests results.

Thanks

Comment: I did that and now got this.
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: None of the test reports contained any result

Comment: so , it looks like the tests doesn't run , do you have any error in the log ? are you sure you run the tests ?

Comment: Is there any plugin to run the tests in Jenkins?

Comment: there are a lot of plugins in Jenkins. how to you run the tests now ? it looks like an ant script , if it is you can ru n- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin

if it's not ANT , let me know what it is ...

Comment: Yes i am running an  Ant script

Comment: so make sure you install the plugin and run the relevant task that execute the test.